# add image from url to viewpager in second and third position

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

Here i have two url but when i run this app this images are been loaded to second page means first image will load in second page after few second the second image also adds to same loaction by overlapping. i need to add this to second and third pages these url

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;

        private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.slider,
                R.drawable.slider,
                R.drawable.slider,
        };

        ImageAdapter(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
         return GalImages.length;
         //   return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
            new LoadImage(imageView).execute("http://www.gadgetbaazar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Top-Mobile-Phones.jpg");
            new LoadImage(imageView).execute("https://pisces.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/store/ee/2015/com/pm/nav_desktops_1115.jpg");
            container.addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }



        private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
            ImageView img=null;
            public LoadImage(ImageView img){
                this.img=img;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
                if(image != null){
                    img.setImageBitmap(image);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to load three different images to viewpager right?

Comment: one image from drawer and other two from url

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but have you tried playing with the position ? Let's say, if in instantiateItem() if position == 1, load the first URL, and if position == 2, load the second URL

Comment: ya but i dont know how to set postiion

Comment: you already get the position as an argument in the instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) . So you can use the position inside that function, as it is given to you by the adapter.

Comment: But am not passing to it from where can i pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            if(position == 0){
            imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
            }else if(position == 1){
            new LoadImage(imageView).execute("http://www.gadgetbaazar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Top-Mobile-Phones.jpg");
            }else if(position ==2){
            new LoadImage(imageView).execute("https://pisces.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/store/ee/2015/com/pm/nav_desktops_1115.jpg");
            }

            container.addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
```